# Login Authentication in react and laravel is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, json, reactjs, laravel

For my Project I am using Laravel and React.js. I have already created the login page with the required function in admin panel. Now I can login to my system. But the issue is, when i am trying to log in using wrong password or email, it will redirect to home page. But when I tried using postman its works but not working when I log in using frontend which I have developed.

This is the login function I used in laraval,

```
function login(Request $req)
{
    $user= User::where('email',$req->email)->first();
    if(!$user || !Hash::check($req->password,$user->password))
    {
        return["error"=>"Email or password is not matched"];
    }
    return $user;
}
```

This is the login Page I used in react.js

```
 import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
 import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
 import Header from './Header';
 function Login()
 {
  const [email,setEmail]=useState("");
  const[ password,setPassword]=useState("");
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('user-info'))
    {
        history.push("/home")
    }
 },[]) 
 async function login()
 {
    console.warn(email,password)
    let item={email,password};
    let result=await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify(item),
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Accept":'application/json'
        }
    });
    result=await result.json();
    localStorage.setItem("user-info",JSON.stringify(result))
    history.push("/")
 }
 return(
    <div>
        <Header/>
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <div className="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="email" onChange= 
         {(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/><br/>
        <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="password" onChange= 
        {(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}/><br/>
        <button onClick={login} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   )
  }
 export default Login
```

How can I solve this problem? An well as I want to know that, is there any code that i can insert to login page (react.js) to get the message when the password or email is not matching?

Thank you for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

So you have to check the API response once the API call is finished and this is the place where you have to put the check:

```
result=await result.json();
```

Once you get the `result`, check if the response is for successful login or failure and according to that show notification when it fails and on success set the token in local storage otherwise not.

Ex:

```
if( result.status === 'status from API' )  // check status here
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Can I know the exact coding should be come inside this if function? Including the "else" as well.

Answer (score 0):

your login function need to return status code if the user was successfully logged in or not

```
function login(Request $req)
{
    $user= User::where('email',$req->email)->first();
    if(!$user || !Hash::check($req->password,$user->password))
    {
        return response()->json(["error"=>"Email or password is not matched"],400);;
    }
    return response()->json(["user"=> $user],200);;
}
```

then in your react application you check the status of the response from the api

```
async function login()
 {
    console.warn(email,password)
    let item={email,password};
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify(item),
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Accept":'application/json'
        }
    });
    
    if(response.ok){
        result= await result.json();
        localStorage.setItem("user-info",JSON.stringify(result.user))
        history.push("/")
    }else{
       //error feedback
     }
 }
```